# Doctrine Compund Keys

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have these 3 table

"Business" with these fields:  Id, Name, etc..
"City" with these fields:  Id, Name, etc..

And then I have a table called BusinessCity (given that a bussines can be related to many cities). This table has the fields "BusinessId" and "CityId".

Im trying to relate the CityId to the City entity, and BusinessId to the business entity, on the class BusinessCity. I've been googling this for the past 3 days and couldnt find an answer, if this has been asked before im sorry i didnt see it. Could anyone help me or give me some pointers on how to get this done. Thanks in advance

Comment: could u pls share your table structure ?

Comment: hm if you have not already implemented ... maybe take a look at my answer. took a while to answer and meanwhile you accepted mahok's ... put some work into the examples :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is a bi-directional **many-to-many** relation with a **joinTable**.

Many businesses can reside in multiple cities and in one city there can be multiple businesses.

In a many-to-many relationship either side can be the owning side. JoinTable definition can be left out and has sensible defaults but if you want to specify it concretely i included it in the example.

**Business** (in this example: *owning side = inversedBy = JoinTable definition*)

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Your/Bundle/City", inversedBy="businesses",cascade="{persist,merge}" fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="BusinessCity",
 *    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="business_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *  )
 */
protected $cities;

public function __construct()
{
   $this->cities = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getCities()
{
   return $this->cities;
}

public function setCities(Collection $cities)
{
   // using map with closure to have dublicate/type-checking provided by addCity
   $this->cities->map(function($city) {
       $this->addCity($city);
   });

   return $this;
}

public function addCity(CityInterface $city)
{
    // ... you don't want dublicates in your collection
    if (!$this->cities->contains($city)) {
       $this->cities->add($city);
    }

   return $this;
}

public function removeCity(CityInterface $city)
{
    $this->cities->removeElement($city);

    return $this;
}
// other properties and methods ..
```

**City** (*inverse side = mappedBy*)

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Your/Bundle/Business", mappedBy="cities")
 */
protected $businesses;

// getters & setters ...
// other properties and methods ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty simple, all you have to do is define your JoinTable. It's not easy to find in the docs, but there is an example in the section [Composite Primary Keys](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-3-join-table-with-metadata).

In short, all you have to do is use oneToMany/manyToOne-associations with the class representing your JoinTable instead of directly associating both Business and City with ManyToMany-associations.